# How to create a IF formula that searches for multiple (more than three) text options

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet to track pitches (I'm a baseball coach). I have a current sheet that I  have a check box to click if the pitch was a strike or not, and then you have to choose a "result" like a swinging strike or a foul ball or a hit ball. I was wondering if there was a formula that could search for any of those "results" and produce a true false or a 1, 0. Something like:

```
=If(A1, "take strike" or "swinging strike" or "foul ball" or "hit ball"), 1, 0)
```

There will be a total of 14 "results" I want to include in this formula to count all possible "strike" calls. I have other columns set up to total strike and balls based on 1/False. But trying to take one less step out.

I have more things I'd like to do with this sheet and will be back with other questions, but that was my first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
=IF(OR(A1 = "take strike", A1 = "swinging strike", A1 = "foul ball", A1 = "hit ball"),1,0)
```